# Remover conteudo entre dois arquivos

Tags: regex, shell

Tenho dois arquivos. Um arquivo contém palavras como se fosse um dicionário e um outro arquivo, contém registros de Logs. Gostaria que o arquivo que contem as informações (Dicionários) fosse removido do arquivo de Log. Remover a linha de log completa e não apenas a palavra.

Tentativas sem exito:

```
grep -f dicionario.txt -v logs.txt
```

ou

```
while read line; do egrep -v "$line" logs.txt; done < dicionario.txt >> filtrado.txt
```

O primeiro comando, gerou este erro:

```
grep: Refer▒ncia anterior inv▒lida
```

O segundo creio que ele lê a lista de dicionario linha por linha e conforme não vai achando a referencia ele salva em filtrado.txt. Assim o arquivo filtrado.txt fica em torno de 180 MB, enquanto o arquivo original de Log tem apenas 3 MB.

Conteudo do x.txt

```
Aaroon NB / Inv. 8120403678
ABRIGO SALAS  -  RIFA DE MAIO 2018
Academia e fatura cartão
Acesso por celular
Adequate! I wish to talk.
Adesivos
adventurous, I wish to speak:-)
AIR CROSS
Aluguel Anderson - porto feliz
ANALISTA DE FOLHA PGTO SR
Andamento do seu pedido!
angel
angelic How so?
```

Log.txt

```
May 10 03:29:23 xxxxxxx[28161]: ID: xxxxx; IP: xxxxx; MSGID: <xxxx.xxxx@xxx.com.br>; X-UOL-SMTP: xxxx; SENDER: <xxx@xxx.com.br>; SUBJECT: Коммерческое предложение главному; URL: xxx.com.br;
```

Grato.

Comment: Informe a linguagem de programação usada.

Comment: Usei Expressão regular, shell.

Comment: Qual o conteúdo dos arquivos? Pelo menos uma parte.

Comment: Editei meu comentário com o conteudo.

Answer (score 0):

Use o **`SED`**, encontre um padrão nas linhas que quer excluir `sed '/<padrão que contem na linha que deseja excluir do arquivo/d' dicionario.txt >> filtrado.txt`

Comment: Boa Tarde. Resolvi meu problema de uma forma bem simples {grep -fF arquivo_total.txt -v arquivo_dados_a_ser_removidos.txt} Abraços.